# Unable to deploy app on Emulator (Android Studio says it is rooted)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to deploy an android app on Android Emulator (Nexus 5X API:24), but when the app runs on the phone it says

> This app cannot be used on devices on which the rights limitations
>   were breached (rooted)[3.3]

I have tried creating  a new AVD as well.

[image]

Comment: Please read. It may help. [How To Trick Apps Into Thinking Your Android Is Not Rooted](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/trick-apps-android-rooted/)